# django form.as_table form.errors rendering in row, not pop up

Tags: django, forms, django-templates

I was always under the impression that django form errors would have a small popup near the form field that explained the error, [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eC5H7.jpg). Instead, mine are rendering in the cell next to the field and completely screwing up the alignment of my table causing everything to look ugly, [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJ8nA.jpg). Is there any common troubleshooting for this. Is it because I am using the as_table shortcut to render that they aren't working?

Comment: Are you sure, that the boxes in the Screenshot are in fact popups? Could be styled __div__s or __td__s aswell.

Answer (score 0):

I use the [Django Crispy Forms library](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) which does a lot of this formatting for me automatically.

If you use Bootstrap, the template pack they describe in the installation guide helps keep the formatting looking good.

It doesn't automatically use tooltips to show the form errors, but it should do a pretty good job of keeping the error messages looking nice on your forms.